# Does marking a method's arguments as final makes the method call faster?

Tags: java, methods, final

I have seen time-sensitive backtracking programs written this way and I guess it makes the compiler avoid some memory copy and make a faster method call, and I guess this is useful on recursive programs.

But this is speculation by me, I'd like a detailed explanation/article on this or a refutation.

Answer (score 1):

It has zero impact on performance - indeed, it has no runtime effect at all.

If you compile a class that contains 2 methods - one with the parameters marked as final, and the other without - and then look at the bytecode that gets generated for each method, you'll note that there is no difference (other than the method name).

All the *final* keyword does in this context is make it so that you cannot reassign that variable within the method.

Comment: from KC203's link: For Performance

The revised memory model proposed by JSR 133 includes special provisions for final fields, provisions that are absent from the existing specification. Newer VMs already implement this specification, and treat final fields accordingly. Because final fields are assigned exactly once, aggressive optimizations in a multithreaded context become possible. Specifically, a field doesn't need to be ever reloaded, since its value is guaranteed never to change.

Comment: Also: Since a final method is only implemented in the declaring class, there is no need to dynamically dispatch a call to a final method, and static invocation can be used instead. The compiler can emit a direct call to the method, bypassing entirely the usual virtual method invocation procedure. Because of this, final methods are also candidates for inlining by a Just-In-Time compiler or a similar optimization tool. (Remember, private/static methods are already final, therefore always considered for this optimization.)

Comment: so it appears that on ancient JVMs and multithreaded applications there IS a performance gain.

Comment: Your comments refer to final fields and final methods, which are different from final method parameters (which is what your original question referred to).

Comment: This is the correct answer. If the generated byte code is the same, then from the JVM's point of view they are exactly the same.

Comment: This answer is very wrong.  Write some benchmarks before and after final and see for yourself.  Correct use of final and volatile are vital for performance in any multi-threaded app, web servers especially; if it can be final, it should be final.

Comment: It depends on what you're writing. If you're writing a lib that you have no control over what JVM it is ran on then you might want to implement the final optimization so you get similar benchmarks.